# How would marriage look like in a modern setting where there is a "force" that gives happily married couples the gift of biological immortality?

Tags: magic, immortality

I'm actually quite interested in this topic and a consideration as to how people would approach marriage, from a world building perspective, if being happily married made you immortal. Allow me to elaborate my three rules of this immortality and explain it in a bit of detail:

**The Three Rules of **Martial Immortality****

1. *You are only Biologically Immortal.* You can still die from disease, accident or injury like a regular human being can.
2. *All Parties have too be actually happily married.* It's okay to have fights every now and then but as long as you are in love and are content with your marriage then it is okay. No abuse and/or drugging your spouse or yourself to be "high" during marriage.
3. *You remain the age of which you become happily married.* That means that if you get married at the age of 24 and don't work things out until you are 27 but are happy afterwards you are staying in a 27 year old's body.

So these are the three rules of the Immortality in my setting. Otherwise it really doesn't matter what is considered in regards to the coupling. Whether it be regular monogamous couples, to polygamous ones, to incestous ones to etc and etc. Those are the only three rules. Now this "magic" is the only magic in the setting. However as this is a modern day urban fantasy setting the people of this world know the following about this "magic" and that's it.

**Rules about the "Force"**

1. *It is derived from a "Force".* People are unsure if it is a god or natural occurring thing just that it exists. There is something out there and it blesses happily married people with immortality
2. *The forces changes.* Based on context, culture and divergences the immortality varies so long as everyone is happy in the arrangement.
3. *The "Force" can not be beaten, tricked or etc.* It is simply there. It exists. It is arranged as such that if you follow the rules its fine. If you don't then you don't. Both in spirit and letter.
4. *The Force feeds on positive sexual relations*. At it's core the power of this "Force" is fed from the idea that people desire, love and lust for each other as sexual beings. No sex no immortality. So like you gotta fuck at least every other day.

Overall though I thing this is an interesting thing to understand and see. I'm just trying to build a modern early 21st century technology world around this idea of couples, marriage, sex and love and unsure how to derive or change our current "religions" to be the "fantasy counterparts" in this setting.

It's a very deep thought and I was hoping to understand how a "western" civilization would look like but am interested in broader trends or thoughts on life and religion and marriage.

**What does marriage look like if biological immortality is on the line here?**

Comment: What if only one party is happy in the marriage? Will only one age?

Comment: Given how many different sects of Christianity there are on earth. What makes you believe that there would be one specific form of Christianity in your world. It's your world and have a lot of leeway while still remaining within the bounds of what's possible with existing religions, let alone what could be possible in a fictional setting. You'll also want to [edit] this down to ask one and only one question.

Comment: It is an interesting question but fails "the book test": If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: I imagine Christianity is not special in this setting. Christian marriage is much like other marriages.

Comment: Depending on when this mysterious force began acting, what makes you believe that there would be anything recognizable as Christianity or modern western civilization in this world? You cannot introduce a massive change, complete with effective magic, and then pretend that history will follow mostly the same path. VTC as needs more focus, that is, as currently written the question is way too broad to be answered in a resonable space.

Comment: For one thing, drugs WOULD feature prominently. Paxil would be in the water. What about plural marriages where one of three-or-four is unhappy? Too many variables, and "gaming the system" is fundamental to human behavior, so saying it can't be tricked is saying it doesn't really follow rules. I'm guessing you aren't married...

Comment: Editted a bit. And as stated no you can't use drugs.

Comment: Are people who are not into sex/romance considered happy (and hence immortal) in their own company, or are they doomed to never benefit from the Force and just... die?

Comment: The force "feeds" off the positive and loving sexual energy. So you need to have sex. Or you age and die.

Comment: Not a full answer, but such a force would have the second-order effect of showing what works in a marriage.  That is, you wouldn't have to wonder whether your perpetually youthful neighbors had an actual happy marriage, or are just keeping up appearances.  And you might, by extension, know whose advice to actually follow.

Comment: (I expect multiple different dynamics could result in happiness, depending on the participants, so there wouldn't really be "one correct way" to achieve immortality.)

Comment: How does masturbation and narcissism factor in? Could a narcissist fulfill all the requirements through masturbation simply by loving and being happy with themself?

Answer (score 2):

I think there would be a huge amount of implicit gratitude towards your partner as long as the marriage is happy, that would probably reduce the effect of small disturbances and issues have on marriage.

It would be not dissimilar to the marriage before XX century made it optional: both spouses find great value in their marriage since it's virtually irreplaceable as a part of their lives.

An unhappy marriage would likely fall apart very fast. So the marriage would perhaps be like a stablecoin, which only has two stable valuations: 1 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Love Conquers All

Even old age! (But really, expect this thought to be more popular than it is now.)

Any kidding aside, this is just another sign of marriage health. Wedding photos have the side effect of showing how unhappy a marriage has been. This does have they benefit of being mostly visible by both parties. If one partner is dissatisfied, then both see effects of aging and it's a clear signal to work on their relationship.

I would also expect more people to be willing to work on their relationships. It is a much bigger incentive to go to counseling and to really focus on your partners happiness when biological immortality is in the line.

The alternative to repairing a marriage, divorce, seems to be pretty rough: *maybe* you can get happiness in a new relationship, but *maybe* you will age anyways and never find that magic again. *Maybe* it is worth staying in the bad relationship in the hope that it turns good and your aging stops. *Maybe* the shame of aging while married will be a factor for change. It is tough to say!

## Timing Marriage

This does introduce a pressure to get hitched earlier on in life, especially for anyone who values a youthful appearance. This could result in a lot of failed attempts at immortality. After all, if you only married a random person to prevent aging, you may not successfully gain this effect.

This also kinda stinks for women who like older looking men. Perhaps a more dramatic age difference would occur: biologically 19- to 25-ish women marrying 30-35-ish men. (Yes, this is the kind of age difference you see: go read your favorite Jane Austin!) Maybe men, such as it once was, need to make a name for themselves before being considered suitable for marriage. Once again, this is just based on personal preference of individuals and cultures.

Answer (score 1):

### Intense and short-lived

Plenty of people currently put up with marriages that they are unhappy with - for the sake of the children, to keep up appearances, because they fear they won't find anything better, because they have settled into a stable, if not happy, configuration with their partner. Your scenario makes this impossible: first of all, everyone (yourself and your partner included) will know that you're no longer happy, because you start showing signs of aging again; and second, because death is a pretty strong motivator.

Any pressure from society to remain in an unhappy marriage would probably vanish: it's obvious to everyone that you're not happy, so there are no appearances to keep up. Religions wouldn't get away with mandating lifelong monogamy if the "'til death do us part" vow became self-fulfilling.

Worried about losing years of life to subtle aging whilst being less-than-ecstatically in love, people will tend to seek the intense passion of new dalliances - when romance and longing are most obvious, and with them the certainty that you are getting the Force in full force, so to speak.

Larger configurations and open relationships may also become more common as people try to avoid the inevitable ups and downs of an exclusive relationship - dipping their fingers into multiple Force pies could help ensure that you have at least one person you're happily in love with at any one time, and therefore you are protected from ageing.

Comment: Interesting point about the open relationship question! Normally, the concept of a marriage is incompatible with open relationships, but the only thing that would matter in this case is what the "force" does. I hope the OP sees your answer and clarifies their intentions.

Comment: @Qami They do not need to be open relationships, but could be polygamious closed relationships.